# Do bass singers' voices deepen after puberty? If so, by how much?

Tags: voice, bass-voice

I have heard that bass voices tend to continue deepening well after puberty, sometimes into the early thirties. Is this true? I believe Geoff Castellucci once said in an interview that at eighteen he was proud that he could hit an E2, but now he sings the occasional F#1. Is he purely an anomaly, or is he an extreme example of a typical phenomenon?

For a quick follow-up to this, as an eighteen-year-old low baritone who can reach a D2 fairly consistently, is it reasonable to expect C2s and lower someday, or is this likely out of reach?

Comment: I've gained about a semitone at the low end in 40 years. [of course, to compensate I've lost a good half an octave off the top.] Don't hold your breath & don't wish too hard or you might just get your wish ;)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, a voice is not 'finished' at 18! Voices continue to mature in both timbre and range for many years.

However, I don't know that you can necessarily *expect* an increase: physiology, technique, and practice will have a part to play.